Helper function for getting the address of a variable
In the Go codebase I am looking at, I frequently see stuff like the following:
some_func(&SomeStructType{
  some_attribute: get_ptr(some_object.some_var),
  ....
)}

func get_ptr[T any](val T) *T {
    return &val
}

I don't understand why get_ptr is needed. Is there any material difference between this and
some_func(&SomeStructType{
  some_attribute: &(some_object.some_var),
  ....
)}

?
I've been reading a bit on garbage collection and heap/stack allocation in Go, and think I have the basics down, but I still don't grasp why the helper would be needed here.

The function is for values that are not addressable.  Integer literals are one example:  get_ptr(1)

@CeriseLimón I see, but some_object.some_var isn't a literal value right? or perhaps I am not understanding the meaning of literal value here

The get_ptr functions were created to handle non-addressable values. Because value in the question is addressable, the function is probably not needed there. There is a material difference between the two options in the question: &(some_object.some_var) is a pointer to a field insome_object and get_ptr(some_object.some_var) is pointer to a copy of the field's value.

This has nothing to do with stack/heap.

Is there a difference? Yes, the function called with & can change the source variable, while the function called with get_ptr gets a pointer to a copy and can not:
func main() {
    someObject := someObjectType{someVar: 1}

    fmt.Println("main before someFunc getPtr SomeVar:", someObject.someVar)

    someFunc(&SomeStructType{
        someAttribute: getPtr(someObject.someVar),
    })

    fmt.Println("main after someFunc getPtr SomeVar:", someObject.someVar)

    fmt.Println()

    fmt.Println("main before someFunc & SomeVar:", someObject.someVar)

    someFunc(&SomeStructType{
        someAttribute: &someObject.someVar,
    })

    fmt.Println("main after someFunc & SomeVar:", someObject.someVar)
}

func someFunc(someObject *SomeStructType) {
    fmt.Println("someFunc before ++ someAttribute:", *someObject.someAttribute)
    *someObject.someAttribute++
    fmt.Println("someFunc after ++ someAttribute:", *someObject.someAttribute)
}

someFunc before ++ someAttribute: 1
someFunc after ++ someAttribute: 2
main after someFunc getPtr SomeVar: 1

main before someFunc & SomeVar: 1
someFunc before ++ someAttribute: 1
someFunc after ++ someAttribute: 2
main after someFunc & SomeVar: 2

Try it on the Go Playground.
Why is it done that way in the codebase you are looking at? I don't know, since I don't know which codebase you are looking at.
I see this sometimes done in automatically generated APIs (e.g. AWS Smithy does this to make everything optional (using nil pointers for “not set”)), and this is an easy way to take pointers to literal values, so there it is used for a different purpose. It's not Go idiomatic, though.
